# How to save contenteditable input to a variable so I can print it on screen

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and I want to save a contenteditable text to a variable so i can print it on screen.
HTML:

```js
function saveEdits() {
    //get the editable element
    var editElem = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=editElem;
    //write a confirmation to the user
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Title</h1>
    <input type="button" value="save edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
    <p id="update"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want this :

```js
function saveEdits() {
    //get the editable element
    var editElem = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=editElem;
    //write a confirmation to the user
    alert("your text have been saved");
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type content here" id="myText">
<input type="button" value="save edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
    <p id="update"></p>
```

The text is stocked in the `editElem` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using `innerHTML`:

```
function saveEdits() {
    //get the editable element
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
    //write a confirmation to the user
}
```

Comment: Most welcome. Can you then mark the solution as solved and upvote plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change .**value** to .**innerHTML** .

```js
function saveEdits() {
//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=editElem;
//write a confirmation to the user
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Title</h1>
    <input type="button" value="save edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
    <p id="update"></p>
```